# How/can you install an older version of Blender?

Tags: installation

How or can you install an older version of Blender? The current version you can install is 2.82a, although, I would like version 2.78c. I cannot find it on the website if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

All release of Blender are still available for [download](https://download.blender.org/release/), reaching back to the very first version of Blender for the IRIX operating system.

The files for Blender 2.78c can be found [here](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.78/).

Comment: Many thanks. Really helps.